# query for finding specific data using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table which contain id(**primary key**), user-id (f**oreign key** ) and roles( having some roles like USER, ADMIN, SYSTEMADMIN). An user may have multiple roles. I want to find those user only having role USER but not other privileges. I give a snapshot of a similar table. How can I do it.

[Image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9rqb.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subselect for exclude the userid different from user

```
select distinct userid from my_table 
where  userid is not in ( select userid from my_table where roles != 'USER')
and roles ='USER';
```

or you can  use an having  for count(distinct roles)

```
select userid from my_table
where roles = 'USER' 
having count( distinct roles) = 1
group by userid
```